# Why does this PHP block only run if a print_r precedes it?

Tags: php

this simple PHP snippets fails to echo `date` property.

```
<?php
$date_time = new DateTime;
echo $date_time->date;
```

result

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DateTime::$date in /tmp/fiddle.php on line 5
```

If I add in a `print_r()` statement it works:

```
<?php
$date_time = new DateTime; print_r($date_time);
echo $date_time->date;
```

result

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23 00:14:01
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Pacific/Auckland
)
2016-02-23 00:14:01
```

Why is PHP doing this?

Comment: Use `$date_time->format()` to output the content of the DateTime object.

Comment: this is a known issue, have a look at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382

Comment: Initially reported in 2009.  Pretty lame that this has been a known bug and unfixed for approaching 7 years.  It surely can't be a hard thing to fix!